# trigger to update lookup fields in 2 object lookup fields

Tags: trigger, relationships

trigger to update lookup fields in 2 object lookup fields
My requirement is :

a) i am having 2 lookup fields in 2 different objects with fields with common fields **"city"**

If i update a city using lookup for example **california** is **changed to** **washington** the **change must update all records which have california must be changed to washington.**

**ex:- accounts and contacts objects has common field city if i update city field in accounts then it must update in contacts also.**

Answer (score 2):

Since the two field is updated together. Why not just consolidate the two fields to one ?

Just create another formula field in the contact object (child), and make it reference to account's city.

Or it can be done to update the responding fields by using workflow + field update. The case is simple and you don't need to write a trigger.

However, I can't see why it need to separate them to two different fields.

Comment: Dear user4986:

  So your issue is how to avoid "trigger looping" right ?